# Enable plugins that are "not supported"

Tags: plugins, database, options, configuration

I just create a **clone of a website** with *All-in-One WP Migration*, the original site being **hosted on wordpress.com**. Since wordpress.com is a typical managed WordPress provider, it allows only for a limited "supported" number of plugins to be installed.

Now on my **clone**, which is **hosted on a common webserver** (not managed) I want to install some of those plugins, that are not available on the original site. However, even there I can't install them. They are still "not supported".

[image]

My question is: **What can I do to install and enable these plugins?** I have total access via FTP and also to the database.

Comment: Just trying to think about how this would've been implemented, is there anything in a wp-content/mu-plugins folder?

Comment: Yes! There is something called 'wpcomsh' in the 'wp-content/mu-plugins' folder.

Comment: Try renaming the `mu-plugins` folder, which will disable it. Having never seen wpcomsh personally I don't know what else it does, but I presume that it's responsible for adding these limits.

Comment: `mu-plugins` are 'must-use' plugins and can't be deactivated through the UI, so on a system like .com where you don't have access to FTP or the server it's the logical place to add additional functionality to a WordPress install that the user can't disable.